# Change Image Dynamically in Android

Tags: android

I can set an image dynamically in Android but

how about having 5 images and every time I click on the button it should change the image in imageview. but 5 images are done reset old images..pls help me..

```
OnClick(View v){
if(counter == 0){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
}
if(counter == 1){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
}
if(counter == 2){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
}
if(counter == 3){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4);
}
if(counter == 4){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image5);
}
if(counter == 5){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image6);
    counter = -1;
}
counter++}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just based on our logic. Please think yourself.

```
 if(counter == 0){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
counter++;
}else if(counter == 1){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
counter++;
}else if(counter == 2){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
counter++;
}else if(counter == 3){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4);
counter++;
}else if(counter == 4){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image5);
counter++;
}else{

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image6);
    counter=0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution would be to store those drawable IDs in an array and pick from it by index

```
    int counter = 0;
    Integer[] images =  {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5}
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.setImageResource(images[counter]);
            if(counter++ >= images.length) counter = 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'd improve (and simplify) it with ` imageView.setImageResource(images[counter % images.length]);` (and remove the next line)

Comment: @Orabîg, Removing the next line will also remove the increment operation, so it doesn't make sense. Additionally, in a very unlikely case, you can hit integer overflow, so I'd go with nullifying the counter every time it goes out of bounds.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I forgot "counter++" instead of "counter" which you must have guessed :) (and I also think that hitting the Integer.MAX_VALUE is also very unlikely)